# avoid Bluetooth DUN authorisation with paired devices

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.1-jelly-bean, bluetooth-tethering

I have two Android phones - one has 4.0.1 ICS and other has 4.1 jelly bean.
I have enabled Bluetooth tethering on ICS . 
I have also paired both the devices via Bluetooth.
Now what I want is that when I connect jelly bean phone to ICS for network access(via DUN) ,the ICS phone should allow it without asking user's permission again and again when I try to connect.
(this is similar feature seen in Nokia phones ,auto connection)
how do I do this ?